# How can I access Lightspeed POS R series api in my google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, lightspeed

I'm building a script to import some inventory from lightspeed to a Google sheet to then be used by Meta for their online retail service. Is there a way to generate a client ID and key without needing a user to actually push a button to request access. I guess I'm just a little lost on how I would implement the API into a Google apps script.

I haven't tried to use the oauth yet.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.